# rvm not defaulting to newer version of ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I am using ruby on rails on Ubuntu 11.10. Ruby 1.8.7 works fine but I cannot get rvm to work with 1.9.3 or any other version.

When I run rvm reload, rvm list or rvm info, I get the following message:

> bash: /usr/bin/rvm: No such file or directory

I have Ruby 1.9.3 installed via rvm and when I change the default it doesn't give me an error. But then when I check the ruby -v it defaults back to 1.8.7.

Also, when I check which ruby it shows the following:

> /usr/local/bin/ruby

My guess is that it has something to do with the bash file. What do you suggest?

I am guessing that it isn't even installing it correctly.

This is what happens:
I type the following into the prompt:

```
bash < <(curl -sk https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
```

And it outputs:

> ERROR: Unable to checkout branch .

Comment: Have you emailed the author of RVM directly? Wayne is very responsive and has been able to help me the few times I had a question. Get his email from the output of `rvm version`, and send him an email describing what you have done and include the output of `rvm info`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you following the installation instructions from the rvm site?
http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/

If you are then look at section 2 about the shell again.
specifically this command that they tell you to run :-)

```
echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

remember to reload or restart your shell after running that command.

Comment: I'll have to try re-installing it... I did follow those instructions but it is still not working right.

Answer (score 1):

run the command

```
source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm
```

and then

```
type rvm | head -1
```

you should get output -

```
rvm is a function.
```

And after that run

```
rvm use rvm use 2.0.0 --default
```